# spring data jpa multiple sorting

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and JQGrid. I need response based on multiple sort parameters.
I tried using sort parameter=column a,column b and sort order=asc but I am getting an exception

> :No property column a,column b found in pojo.

It works if I would pass either of one columns as sort parameter.
Code:

```
Pageable pageable = JPAUtility.constructPageSpecification(pageNumber, rowsPerPage, sortColName, sortOrder);
```

How can I pass multiple column names in `sortColName` parameter?

Answer (score 8):

In Spring Data you just need to add Sort parameter into findBy* method. Sort object has got a couple constructors, e.g.

```
Sort(Direction direction, String... properties)
```

which is probably exactly what you need. If you need to specify different directions for various properties then you can use

```
Sort(Order... orders)
```

where Order has property and direction: `Order(Direction direction, String property)`