# In JPA Query, can I pass the order by property and DESC/ASC order as parameters in the method signature?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using spring framework and working repository level implementations.

I have a class:

`@Repository
public interface MyClassReadRepository extends ReadRepository<MyClass, Integer>`

In this class there is a method that looks like this:

`@Query("SELECT a FROM MyClass a WHERE a.type IN :myType ORDER BY :someProperty :someOrder")
Page<MyClass> findByTypeAndOrder(@Param("myType") List<MyType> myType, @Param("someProperty")String someProperty, @Param("someOrder")String someOrder, Pageable pageable)`

But apparently the Query structure is wrong: ":someProperty" should be an identifier...

My question is: how to pass order and sort parameters in the example above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Google for spring data jpa. 2. click on the link to the reference documentation. 3. hit Cmd-F (or Ctrl-F) 4. type "sort". And here it goes: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890885/spring-data-jpa-multiple-sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
PageRequest(page, size, direction, properties)
```

Creates a new PageRequest with sort parameters applied.
Parameters:

**page**: zero-based page index. (like 5 or 10 etc)

**size**: the size of the page to be returned. (like 50 or 100 etc)

**direction**: the direction of the Sort to be specified, can be null. (like Sort.Direction.ASC)

**properties**: the properties to sort by, must not be null or empty. (like "my column name")

Answer (score 4):

You are already passing a Pageable object. You can pass your params as follows

```
new PageRequest(1, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "yourProperty");
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: how to pass order and sort parameters in the example above?

In JPA (and JDBC) parameters are placeholders for *values*, not for more general query text.  You cannot use them in place of identifiers such as column or table names, nor in place of keywords such as `ASC` / `DESC`.

Queries that have similar form but differ in one or more identifiers or keywords are fundamentally different queries.  You need different `Query`s to represent them.